# Mongodb findOneAndUpdate is not working

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update document in mongodb collection but it's not working for me. Here is the function all fields are come to the backend. I use mlab online mongo db

```
router.post(
  '/accept',
  (req,res) => {
    const leaveFields = {};
    leaveFields._id = req.body.id;
    leaveFields.name = req.body.name;
    leaveFields.reason = req.body.reason;
    leaveFields.from = req.body.from;
    leaveFields.to = req.body.to;
    leaveFields.user_id = req.body.user_id;
    leaveFields.leaveType = req.body.leaveType;
    console.log(req.body.id);
    Leave.find({user_id:req.body.user_id})  //{ "_id":ObjectId("req.body.id") }
      .then(leave =>{
        if(leave){
          Leave.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id : req.body.id},
            {$set : leaveFields},
            {new : true}
        )}else{
          res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
      }
        )
      .catch(err=>res.status(404).json({ noleavefound: 'No leaves found' }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are setting _id to leavefields object and

```
const leaveFields = {};
leaveFields._id = req.body.id;
```

here you are passing _id field also to your update.

```
{$set : leaveFields}
```

_id field is an immutable filed. So, Exclude _id field and then check.